# How to provide an error message if user input doesn't match options given?

Tags: bash

I have a script that looks something like this.

```
until [[ "${answer}" = "exit" ]]
do
if [[ "${answer}" = "<option a>" ]]
then
    <input some text>
fi
if [[ "${answer}" = "<option b>" ]]
then
    <input some other text>
fi
done
```

My problem is that I want to provide an error message if the user types in anything that doesn't match the options given, and I can get it to do that, but it will still provide the error message when the user types anything in after triggering one of the conditional if/then statements.
I tried doing something like this under my until/do statement.

```
 if [ "${answer}" != "<option a>" ] || [ "${answer}" != "<option b>" ]
 then
     echo "Invalid input"
```

But it still returns the error message due to the requested input in the various if/then statements.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check if the initial input does not match any of your options, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

answer=$1

until [[ "$answer" == @(exit|option a|option b) ]]; do
  printf >&2 'Invalid option %s\n' "$answer"
  exit 1
done

##: Process the rest of the script here.
```

---

If that is not the case, then maybe provide more info.